# FieldValue.increment causing Flutter crash

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
static Future<void> updateBalanceAmount(
  {int amount, String balanceId, String userId}) {
  var updateBalance = _db
    .document('account/$userId/balance/$balanceId')
    .updateData({'balance_amount': amount});
  return updateBalance;
}



static Future<void> addCreditAmount(
  {int amount, String balanceId, String userId}) async {
  final DocumentReference ref = _db.document('account/$userId/balance/$balanceId');
  await ref.updateData(<String, dynamic> {
    'balance_amount': FieldValue.increment(amount),
  });
}
```

Can someone explain why the top function works while the bottom function crashes? Specifically, I need to implement FieldValue.increment in Flutter but it consistently crashes when I try.

Here is the stack trace:

/libc    (18226): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8 in tid 18285 (1.raster), pid 18226 (app.matto.com)

---

Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:11/RSR1.200819.001.A1/6823625:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2021-02-18 10:11:50-0500
pid: 18226, tid: 18285, name: 1.raster  >>> app.matto.com <<<
uid: 10153
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
Cause: null pointer dereference
eax 00000000  ebx c33c4920  ecx fffffff9  edx 00000000
edi 00000004  esi 00000000
ebp c158a648  esp c158a648  eip c2d12de5
backtrace:
#00 pc 013cbde5  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#01 pc 013e4673  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#02 pc 0146c58e  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#03 pc 0163fad3  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#04 pc 0163f9a5  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#05 pc 0163fe93  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#06 pc 0163fc7f  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#07 pc 011f53b5  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#08 pc 011f600a  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#09 pc 011f6e32  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#10 pc 011a3f9b  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#11 pc 011f58e4  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#12 pc 011f564c  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#13 pc 0120376f  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#14 pc 011aa38f  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#15 pc 011acee5  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#16 pc 011acdf6  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#17 pc 011b357e  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#18 pc 011b35ac  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#19 pc 00019337  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::SimpleLooperCallback::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+39) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
#20 pc 0001a367  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+1127) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
#21 pc 00019e96  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+118) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
#22 pc 000133f5  /system/lib/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+101) (BuildId: f98006d4d736575082b552ff24b66f6c)
#23 pc 011b34bb  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#24 pc 011acda4  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#25 pc 011ac8fc  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#26 pc 011b0a2d  /data/app/~~qml9am1bePmidpLuDa7Bmg==/app.matto.com-mJtCM3HEUFtPk_pMu3CaCA==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (BuildId: 1c148fb28fc7334c78622f67843cff2825d62c72)
#27 pc 000e6964  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100) (BuildId: a690ed60a8b6a282b41dd991389b5fdb)
#28 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71) (BuildId: a690ed60a8b6a282b41dd991389b5fdb)

Comment: If the app crashes, what is the exact error message and stack trace that you get?

Comment: I added it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately iOS stack traces are really hard to parse (for me at least). I don't immediately see what's going wrong here, and how Firestore is involved (from the stack trace), but hopefully somebody else spots it.

Comment: I see a null reference in the stack trace.  Have you stepped through the function with a debugger to see if any null values pop up?  Also, you might want to wrap the function in a try catch on FirebaseException and print the error.message.